# Germany Visa Rejection

Tags: visa

Recently after receiving a job offer of a parcel delivery driver in Germany I started the process of visa processing. All required documents were provided to the Embassy but unfortunately I was rejected with a letter that states that;

> Sehr geehrter Herr Peter,

> die Deutsche Botschaft Kampala bedauert, Ihnen mitteilen zu müssen,
> dass Ihrem Antrag auf Erteilung eines Visums nach Abschluss der Prüfung auf Grundlage Bestimmungen nicht entsprochen werden kann. Die für die Ablehnung Ihres Antrages wesentlichen
> nachfolgend mitgeteilt:
> geltenden der ausländerrechtlichen
> tragenden Gründe werden Ihnen
> Sie beabsichtigen die Einreise nach Deutschlad zur Erwerbstätigkeit als
> Paketzusteller bei der S und S Logistic GmbH.
> Ein erforderlicher Tatbestand nach der BeschV bzw. nach dem AufenthG ist unter Beachtung Ihrer Nationalität und der angestrebten Tätigkeit nicht vorhanden.
> Eine Erteilung des Visums nach 24a BeschV als Berufskraftfahrer kommt hier nicht in Betracht, da Sie über keine entsprechende
> Fahrerbescheinigung im Sinne des Artikel 5 Absatz 1 der Verordnung
> EG) Nr. 1072/2009 verfügen.
> Rechtsbehelfsbelehrung:
> Gegen diesen Bescheid kann innerhalb eines Monats nach Bekanntgabe
> Klage beim Verwaltungsgericht Berlin erhoben werden. Sie haben darüber hinaus die Möglichkeit, diesen Bescheid innerhalb
> eines Monats nach Bekanntgabe von der Botschaft Kampala prüfen zu
> lassen (Remonstration)

> Seite 2 von 2

> Während der Remonstration können Sie weiterhin innerhalb der oben genannten Frist gegen diesen Bescheid Klage erheben, allerdings wird das Remonstrationsverfahren dadurch beendet und der Bescheid nur noch
> im Klageverfahren überprüft. Wird der Visumantrag nach Uberprüfung durch die Auslandsvertretung erneut abgelehnt, so ergeht ein weiterer Bescheid (Remonstrationsbescheid), gegen den sodann Klage bei dem Verwaltungsgericht Berlin erhoben werden kann. Bitte begründen Sie
> Ihre Remonstration und fügen Sie geeignete Nachweise bei, soweit dies
> nicht mit dem Visumantrag geschehen ist.
> Mit freundlichen Grüßen
> im Auftrag
> Averkamp

All your advise will be highly appreciated. What can I do on my side to rectify this as I have already communicated to the employer in Germany but seems to have run out options. Please expatriates advise me accordingly.

Comment: The absolute reason for rejection is that you don't have the required driver's license to do the job you are intending. I assume that you are an Ugandan citizen and I am not sure if you have a right to a work permit even with the correct driver's license. Which reasons do you have to believe that you are supposed to get a work permit?

Comment: This means you do not have the required EU Driver's Licence **and** no working contract that insures that employer will get you one. [§ 24a BeschV - Einzelnorm](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/beschv_2013/__24a.html)

Comment: @Peter.E Are you sure the job offer is legitimate? It seems strange that a German-based parcel delivery company would offer a job to a person requiring a work visa when that person has neither the necessary EU driver’s licence nor a work contract that would make you eligible for a visa.

Comment: No German company will sponsor a visa for driver job, embassies don’t issue visa for jobs that are not highly skilled or in shortage (truck driver in some country is in shortage though)

Comment: I absolutely appreciate all your efforts of advising me but However what the possible solutions to this issue. According to my understanding, I thought that EU drivers license can be obtained while there after a series of training and paper.

Comment: You may have to accept that you have no options here. The embassy probably does not believe your request is legit. 
Getting a driving licence in Germany costs quite a bit of money, especially if the job requires you to get a truck driver's licence. This could easily be several 1000s of Euro. And for a truck driving licence you would need to pass a medical test as well. 
But having a licence is not enough. That does not make you a professional driver. You need other training as well. And how is your German?